# How to pass array of functions Object.assign and pass the same argument to every of them

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a following line of code:

```
return Object.assign({}, generators(config));
```

If the `generators` is of type `Function` the code compiles and executes correctly, but the `generators` is of type `Function[]` and I want all of the functions in this array to be executed and have `config` passed to them as an argument.

**Question:**: How to pass multiple functions to the `Object.assign` and pass `config` to them.

Comment: Share fiddle/working code link.Query is not clear

Answer (score 0):

```
var x = Object.assign({}, someFunc([{
  func: func1,
  config: {a:1}
}, {
  func: func2,
  config: {b:2}
}]))


function func1 (config) {
  return config;
}

function func2 (config) {
  return config;
}

function someFunc (list) {
  var obj = {};
  for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
     Object.assign(obj, list[i].func(list[i].config))
  }

  return obj;
}

console.log(x);
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer is:

```
  let temp = generators.map(gen => gen(config));
  return Object.assign({}, ...generators.map(gen => gen(config)));
```